# jquery-ui-map "Get directions" example loaded through AJAX (with examples)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-map

I implemented the [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) "Get directions" [example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map)
All is working fine when the map HTML mark-up is inside the multi-page index.htm, so I'm sure the script works
But in my real-world script I have a list of music shows, each with a different location, so I have to load the map mark-up through AJAX (after some server-side processing to retrieve the address of each location), and in this case I run into two problems:

- the geolocation doesn't work anymore: the browser doesn't ask me if I want to commmunicate my current location
- the "back" button doesn't work anymore: the url in the address bar changes, but the page stays the same

Here is my real examples: please navigate to Next Shows > Club (X) > Get directions and see what happens

- NON AJAX example (working): http://www.iwstudio.it/mobile/index2.htm
- AJAX example (not working): http://www.iwstudio.it/mobile/index.htm

  Downloadable script: http://www.iwstudio.it/mobile/mobile.rar

Any help, please? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by not using AJAX in the map page, the destination location is passed through DOM element